# What is wrong with the seo of my site?

Tags: seo, wordpress

My question is related to the seo performance of my website binarytides.com
My website has recently seen fall in traffic and I have noted that for some of my best keywords the traffic is falling, and moreover websites with poorer content are out performing my website in the google search results.

Here is a simple case

Post
http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd/

Keyword :

packet sniffer code in c

For the given keyword my post used to be on 1st position for 2 years. Recently it has started falling.

What could be the reasons. Few guesses ....

1. Are comments spoiling the seo ? I am under the impression that comments that have content relating to the post content, should add to the seo.
2. Having large amount of "source codes" in the post spoils the seo ? Like too many "printf"
3. If I have 2 articles with title "how to do this" and "how to do this - part 2" then does google treat it bad ?
4. does comment pagination spoil seo (since it creates link to next comment pages in wordpress) ? But I am already using rel="canonical" to indicate the main post url.

Also note that this url copies 1 of my posts as it is, and it comes in the first page along with the my post

http://www.cnblogs.com/rollenholt/articles/2585578.html

So google is considering that post the same worth as mine!!

I used to see such things at bing. So what exactly is happening to google ??

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the SERPs for the specific query you give, it seems likely that there is more competition than there used to be.  And that competition is doing a good job of being user friendly.

Just looking at the top three results, all three look perfectly relevant.  They all use the correct keywords, they all have code that I can use.  Yours and the "Simplest Codings" both have a bit of text explaining the important bits of the code.  All three of the results have enough inbound links that they are likely to be trusted by Google.

When it comes to ordering results that are so good, Google will rely heavily on user interaction signals.  Click through rate (CTR) and bounce back rate (BBR) will probably decide which comes first.

My guess is that "Simplest Coding" has a much higher CTR than your listing for "packet sniffer code in c".

- Uses "create your own" which is a nice call to action for that query
- Uses "simple" which is likely to be appealing for somebody with that query
- You use "BSD" which alienates anybody on Linux, Mac, or Windows (The majority of people searching for that query).

The tcpdump result probably has a higher BBR than the others:  it doesn't have instructions that come with it, it is just the code.

Comment: Can OP tell us whether he has implemented authorship on the site? the search results I got did not seem to show authorship for any of the sites. Implementing that could help in higher CTRs.

Comment: Too much SEO can bury you as much as none at all. Create content for your audience, not a robot. And KEEP IT FRESH!